# how to associate each SQS and DLQ created using for_each with one another in orderly format

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
Terragrunt.hcl

terraform {
  source = "../..//infrastructure/module"
}


include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

inputs = {
  sqs_queue_names                  = ["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"]
  dead_queue_names                 = ["CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"]
}
```

Module that i am calling from my terragrunt configuration

```
Variable.tf
variable "sqs_queue_names"{
  description = "The name of different SQS to be created"
  type        = set(string)
}

variable "dead_queue_names"{
  description = "The name of different Dead Queues to be created"
  type        = set(string)
}
```

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{

    for_each                   = {for idx, val in var.sqs_queue_names: idx => val}
    name                       = each.value
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[each.key].arn
        maxReceiveCount        = var.max_receive_count
    })

    tags = var.default_tags
    
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{

    for_each                   = toset(var.dead_queue_names)
    name                       = each.value
   

    tags = var.default_tags
}
```

An updated code.I am calling the module from my terragrunt configuration to create 2 SQS and 2 DeadLetterQueue.I want terraform to create "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event" and Associate it with "CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event",also to create CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event" and associate it "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"

```
Error Message:
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│   15:         deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[each.key].arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
```

Comment: @Marcin,Yes i am using the exact code that i posted in the question

Comment: I see now. Your previous question did not include data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change:

```
type        = set(string)
```

into

```
type        = list(string)
```

The reason is that `set` can't be accessed by an index.

Comment: @marcin.thank you so much,I am not getting the error anymore but I am getting new error messages with other resources that wasnt affected before after i changed it set(string) to list(string)

Comment: I am getting this error now-----------  Invalid index
│ 
│   on iam.tf line 15, in resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy":
│   15:       "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].arn}",
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Comment: @bibi Could be same reason as in this question. Did you check your data types?

Comment: yes i have changed the data type to what you suggested as well